# Исправление ошибок с кодировкой.

Tags: c#, text

Добрый день. Возникла проблема : есть некий `xml` файл из которого производится чтение. Файл на немецком языке и в нем бытые умляуты.

Строка имеет такой вид : `"Bettbezug Kevin. Handgestickte Bl�ten. Knopfverschluss. Perkal aus reiner Baumwolle (79 F�den/cm�)."`

В нормальном виде должна быть такой : `"Bettbezug Kevin. Handgestickte Blüten. Knopfverschluss. Perkal aus reiner Baumwolle (79 F den/cm )."`

Сам пробывал из разных кодировок приводить к "ISO-8859-1", но максимум что получилось - это заменить "� => ? ".

Так вот, есть ли возможность исправить ошибки с кодировкой и получить нормальную строку?

Спасибо.

Comment: Покажите код чтения файла и пример файла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создал такой xml-файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document name="German text">
  <text>Bettbezug Kevin. Handgestickte Blüten. Knopfverschluss. Perkal aus reiner Baumwolle (79 F den/cm ).</text>
</document>
```

Сохранил в D:\text.xml с кодировкой UTF-8. В нашей программе открываем, парсим по reader.NodeType, выводим сообщение в MessageBox.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const String filename = "D:\\text.xml";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlTextReader reader = null;

            try
            {        
                reader = new XmlTextReader(filename);
                reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                        MessageBox.Show(reader.Value);
                }
            }

            finally
            {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Выводится текст: Bettbezug Kevin. Handgestickte Blüten. Knopfverschluss. Perkal aus reiner Baumwolle (79 F den/cm ).
Без �.
 *_*  Обновлено _  
Раз **исходный** файл "битый" с � вместо ü, то никакими кодировками мы это не вылечим. Нужно прогнать прочитанный исходный xml через условие, меняя � на ü, и на выходе мы получим нормальный текст.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const String filename = "D:\\text.xml";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string oldString, newString = null;
            XmlTextReader reader = null;

            reader = new XmlTextReader(filename);
            reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                {
                    oldString = reader.Value;
                    char[] letter = new char[oldString.Length];
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach(char c in oldString)
                    {
                        if (c == '�')
                            letter[i] = 'ü';
                        else
                        {
                            letter[i] = oldString[i];
                        }
                        newString += letter[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(newString);
                }
            }
            reader.Close();

            //можем записать новый исправленный файл
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.IndentChars = ("    ");
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("D:\\newtext.xml", settings))
            {
                // Write XML data.
                writer.WriteStartElement("document");
                writer.WriteElementString("text", newString);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну да, но у меня в xml файле такой текст : "Bettbezug Kevin. Handgestickte Bl�ten. Knopfverschluss. Perkal aus reiner Baumwolle (79 F�den/cm�)."

Comment: А-а-а, так вам надо заменить встречающиеся в исходном xml символы � на умлауты после чтения? Обновил ответ. Добавил вариант, исправляющий � на ü. Но тогда и F�den/cm� заменится на Füden/cmü

Comment: Вот, мне нужно было узнать о том, можно ли это вылечить...Просто кроне ü могут быть и другие умляуты. Спасибо за ответ.